# Storage Space Running Out?

Tags: cyanogenmod, insufficient-memory, storage, moto-x, adoptable-storage

I have been getting warnings of storage space running out on my Moto X Play running CM13.

So what I did was go into my storage settings and formatted my 64GB external SD card as internal storage.

I tried going into play store and downloading an app and still I get insufficient storage error and my phone is giving me storage is running out errors.

Comment: Please see [tag: insufficient-memory] tag, which has been added to your question for solutions and help. Also adoptable -storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the apps are stored in internal memory all external ? If it is internally stored then by moving to SD card can solve your problem.

In case of externally stored I guess you can do these things :

1. Hard reset your phone
2. Install a good anti virus app
3. Clear the junk files from your phone by installing clean master or like that apps.
4. Check your SD is corrupted or not.
5. Uninstall system apps ( that are not very useful to you - Google drive, google    music and all). This point need root, so try to root your phone first than only you can do this.

You can get many tutorials on rooting on Google just type your phone model it will give you according result.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My phone is rooted. What I did was re-format my external storage as internal, and I was given the option of moving 5gb of internal files to the external and that seemed to work.

Comment: Okay that's great so it resolved your problem right ?

Comment: I wouldn't really say your answer specifically resolved the problem, I figured it out more or less myself, but I will accept your answer as it may help someone else in the future.